# Как перейти на 28 API в андроид студио?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk

В playmarkete пишет такую ошибку:

> Целевой уровень API для вашего приложения – 26. Чтобы обеспечить
>   необходимую производительность и безопасность, целевой уровень API
>   должен быть не ниже 28.
>
> С августа 2019 года целевая версия новых приложений должна быть не
>   менее Android 9.0 (API уровня 28). С ноября 2019 года целевая версия
>   обновляемых приложений должна быть не менее Android 9.0 (API уровня
>   28).

В gradle стоит вот это :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ",,,,,,,"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 10
        versionName "1.0.10"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'


    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'io.paperdb:paperdb:2.5'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.rilixtech:materialfancybuttons:1.8.7'
    //  compile project(path: ':devicon-typeface')
    implementation 'com.rilixtech:devicon-typeface:2.0.0.3'


}
```

Вопрос можете посоветовать какие прописать  implementetion для 28 api? или указать на ссылки в документации

Answer (score 4):

Ставишь targetsdk 28, и соответственно все стандартные библиотеки 28 версии подключаешь вместо 26.

Comment: Только лучше сразу перейти с `support` на `AndroidX`, так как к ноябрю всё равно придётся - 29-ой версии `support` уже не будет.

Comment: Получается приложение нужно заново переписывать , я правильно понял?

Comment: Не нужно заново переписывать, но в коде могут вылезти какие то нюансы, всвязи с переходом.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно эту строку:

```
targetSdkVersion 26
```

заменить на эту:

```
targetSdkVersion 28
```

это и есть целевое апи. [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465049/changing-api-level-android-studio) есть подобный вопрос по вашей проблеме. В итоге будет выглядеть так:

```
defaultConfig {
   ...
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 28
   ...
}
```

[Вот](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk) есть документация по вашему вопросу. [Вот](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element) описание всех атрибутов которые вы должны использовать в проекте.